# Can I retrieve specific integer datatypes for pandas dataframe columns from a plaintext file?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to store a schema for a set of dataframes in a text file so they can be easily edited and loaded at runtime without defining a lot of dataframes and labels in my code (a few of them should also get stored with some initial values, so I can't have only column labels available in the file). I need to specify integer datatypes for some columns rather than a generic integer type. The only pandas functionality I'm aware of that might work is to store and retrieve the dataframes as JSON using `pandas.read_json(orient='table')`, but this only handles a generic `"integer"` type that's converted to `int64` on the backend, which doesn't work for me. So for a two-column dataframe with types `int8` and `Int16` I'd like to be able to do this

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json('df.json')
print(df, '\n')
print(df.dtypes)
```

and get this output

```py
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [one, two]
Index: []

one     int8
two    Int16
dtype: object
```

but `read_json` only handles `int64`. I can define the table I want, serialize it, and read it back like this

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['one','two']).astype({'one':'int8', 'two':'Int16'})
print(df.to_json(orient='table'), '\n')
print(pd.read_json(df.to_json(orient='table'), orient='table').dtypes)
```

which, after some parsing, results in

```
{
  "schema":{
    "fields":[
      {"name":"index","type":"string"},
      {"name":"one","type":"integer"},
      {"name":"two","type":"integer"}
    ],
    "primaryKey":["index"],
    "pandas_version":"0.20.0"
  },
  "data":[]
}

one    int64
two    int64
dtype: object
```

If I try and change the `"integer"` types to, say, `"int8"`, like this

```py
pd.read_json(df.to_json(orient='table').replace('"integer"', '"int8"'), orient='table').dtypes
```

I get a traceback as below (showing first and last calls only)

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-dc5f6a6f42b4> in <module>
----> 1 pd.read_json(df.to_json(orient='table').replace('"integer"', '"int8"'), orient='table').dtypes

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_table_schema.py in convert_json_field_to_pandas_type(field)
    187             return "object"
    188
--> 189     raise ValueError(f"Unsupported or invalid field type: {typ}")
    190
    191

ValueError: Unsupported or invalid field type: int8
```

The function `convert_json_field_to_pandas_type` in the traceback doesn't seem to handle numeric types beyond `"integer"` and `"number"`, which it converts to `"int64"` and `"float64"` respectively.

What's the most succinct workaround here?

#### Edit

---

If more context is helpful, my current solution is to load a custom json file with this format:

```
{
    "dataframe_name":{
        "df_or_s":"dataframe",
        "type":{
            "column_name":"dtype",
            "column_name":"dtype"
        },
        "values":{
            "column_name":[],
            "column_name":[]
        },
        "index":[]
    },
    "series_name":{
        "df_or_s":"series",
        "type":"dtype",
        "values":[],
        "index":[]
    }
}
```

where

- `"df_or_s"` must be either `"dataframe"` or `"series"`
- `"type"` is a json object with `column_label:dtype` pairs for dataframes or a string with the name of a dtype for series
- `"values"` is a json object with `column_label:value_array` pairs for dataframes or an array of values for series

I then reconstruct the tables as instance attributes of a class like this:

```py
from json import load as json_load
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import Series

class demo:

    def __init__(self, schema='schema.json'):

        if type(schema) == str:

            with open(schema) as f:
                dict_from_json = json_load(f)

            for k,v in dict_from_json.items():

                if v['df_or_s'] == 'dataframe':
                    if len(v['index']) != 0:
                        r = DataFrame(data=v['values'], columns=v['type'].keys(), index=v['index'])
                    else:
                        r = DataFrame(data=v['values'], columns=v['type'].keys())
                    self.__setattr__(k,r.astype(v['type']))

                elif v['df_or_s'] == 'series':
                    if len(v['index']) != 0:
                        r = Series(v['values'], index=v['index'], dtype=v['type'])
                    else:
                        r = Series(v['values'], dtype=v['type'])
                    self.__setattr__(k,r)

                else:
                    raise ValueError('unrecognized value for "'+v['df_or_s']+'" found for name "df_or_s" in tables.json. Must be "dataframe" or "series".')
```